# Python script not creating a text file when run in cmd

Tags: python, text-files

I'm trying to create a python script (with very limited knowledge) that will create a text document on the desktop of whoever runs the program. The section I have that should actually create the text file looks like so:

```
save_path = 'Desktop'
name_of_file = "examplefile"
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")        
file1 = open(completeName, "w+")
toFile = '''text'''
file1.write(toFile)
file1.close()
```

Everything works as intended when run in Visual Studio Code, but when run in CMD, I get the error:

```
  File "file.py", line 101, in <module>
    open(completeName, "w+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Desktop\\examplefile.txt'
```

When run in py.exe, it simply crashes.

I've used `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop>py file.py` and `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop>python3 file.py` to execute the script and had the same error, which I guess doesn't surprise me.

I've looked online quite a bit on how to solve this, but pretty much everything I've seen just restates using `open(filename, "w+")` to create a text file (which I already know) or is in regards to using PATH, which I don't think I need, but admittedly is not something I understand that well.

To summarize, I cannot figure out for the life of me why the script works *exclusively* in VS Code.

Comment: I don't think 'Desktop\\examplefile.txt' is the full path. Try using absolute path for Desktop as savepath

Comment: Try providing complete path `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop` to save_path variable instead of `Desktop`

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the way you've defined the path to the file.

You're trying to create the file `Desktop\examplefile.txt`. So, when you run your script, it looks for the `Desktop` directory from your current working directory (the path where you're running your script from) and creates the `examplefile.txt` file in there.

But the error that you're getting means that it isn't able to find the `Desktop` directory from your current working directory. That's because you're running it from `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop` and there's no `Desktop` directory inside that.

What you should be doing is using a path which will always resolve to the desired directory. For example, if you wanna create a file on the Desktop:

```py
save_path = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], "Desktop")
```

This will always resolve to the user's `Desktop` directory on Windows.

On Windows, the `USERPROFILE` environment variable represents the path to the user's home directory.

And if you're looking for a cross-platform solution to get the user's home directory, you can use this:

```py
# Python 3.5+
from pathlib import Path
home_path = str(Path.home())

# Python 2, <3.5
from os import path
home_path = path.expanduser("~")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Think I recall seeing stuff similar to this, just never pieced it all together.